# How do I make a HTTP POST call with mp4 videos?

Tags: java, apache, http

I want to upload a video to a Java web service using HTTP POST. I am not quite sure how to do it. To upload a file, I do this:

```
static MultipartEntityBuilder http= MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
http.addPart("Test", new Filebody(file));
http.build();
```

Thats how I would do it if I was uploading a file (like pdf). How do I do it for mp4 videos? Can I do it the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way as pdf

```
static MultipartEntityBuilder http= MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
http.addPart("Test", new Filebody(file));
http.build();
```

Always try to run something before posting. The code in your question runs correctly.

Comment: sorry about that. I only have one shot to test it

Comment: No problem. You can always test on localhost instead of your live website.

Comment: I will! How are booleans values handled? Thats not file or String what type is it?